# Unit cube's projections to plane and perpendicular line

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Prove that the area of a unit cube’s projection on any
plane equals the length of the cube’s projection on the perpendicular of
this plane.

Source: Found this problem in solving mathematical problems by terence tao but I couldn't find any solutions online.

Comment: Is this cube in $R^n$ for arbitrary $n$? Or is $n=3$?

Comment: The original question did not specify, but I think $n=3$

Comment: What is "the length of the cube’s projection"?

Comment: I think the cube projection's on a line (perpendicular of a plane) is a segment and therefore it has a length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Volume of a parallelepiped  obtained by [scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) of the three edge vectors
and to the fact that it is invariant under a rotation.

Also have a look at the Volume of a parallelepiped  obtained by [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) of the edge  vectors
$$
{\bf V} = {\bf u}_1  \wedge {\bf u}_2  \wedge {\bf u}_3 
$$
which can be generalized to higher dimension.

As a matter of fact, given $n$ vectors in ${\mathbb R}^m$, their wedge product
$$
{\bf V}_n^{\left( m \right)}  = {\bf x}_1  \wedge {\bf x}_2  \wedge  \cdots  \wedge {\bf x}_n  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\left| {\left\{ r \right\}_{\,k} } \right| = n}  \\
   {\left\{ r \right\}_{\,k}  \in \left\{ {1,2, \cdots ,m} \right\}}  \\
\end{array}} \right.} {V_k \;{\bf e}_{\left\{ r \right\}_{\,k} } } 
$$
where
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 {\bf e}_{\left\{ r \right\}_{\,k} }  = {\bf e}_{j_{\,1} } {\bf e}_{j_{\,2} }  \cdots {\bf e}_{j_{\,n} }  \\ 
 j_{\,1}   < \,  j_{\,2}  <  \cdots  < j_{\,n}  \\ 
 \left\{ r \right\}_{\,k}  = \left\{ {j_{\,1} , j_{\,2} , \cdots ,j_{\,n} } \right\} \in \left\{ {1,2, \cdots ,m} \right\} \\ 
 k = \left[ {1,\binom{m}{n}} \right] \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$

so that the sum is over all the $n$-subsets of $  \left\{ {1,2, \cdots ,m} \right\}$
and $\bf V$ is the $n$-vector associated with the $n$-parallelotope whose edges are parallel to the $\bf x$ vectors.
The magnitude of $\bf V$ represents the ($n$-) volume (absolute value) of that parallelotope:
$$
Vol\left( {{\bf V}_n^{\left( m \right)} } \right) = \left\| {{\bf V}_n^{\left( m \right)} } \right\|
 = \sqrt {\sum\limits_k {V_k ^2 } } 
$$
which is invariant under any unitary transformation.

There are many alternative representations for the volume, mainly the [Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix).
But to focus onto your question, let's rewrite $\bf V$ as
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 {\bf V}_n^{\left( m \right)}  = {\bf x}_1  \wedge {\bf x}_2  \wedge  \cdots  \wedge {\bf x}_n
  = \left( {{\bf x}_1  \wedge {\bf x}_2  \wedge  \cdots  \wedge {\bf x}_{n - 1} } \right) \wedge {\bf x}_n  =  \\ 
  = \left( {{\bf x}_1  \wedge {\bf x}_2  \wedge  \cdots  \wedge {\bf x}_{n - 1} } \right) \wedge {\bf x}_{n\, \bot }
  = {\bf V}_{n - 1}^{\left( m \right)}  \wedge \left\| {{\bf x}_{n\, \bot } } \right\|{\bf u}_{n\; \bot }
  = {\bf V}_{n - 1}^{\left( m \right)}  \wedge \left\| {{\bf x}_n  \cdot {\bf u}_{n\; \bot } } \right\|{\bf u}_{n\; \bot }  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
Here ${\bf x}_{n\, \bot }$ indicates the projection of ${\bf x}_n$  onto the sub-space orthogonal to the sub-space spanned by ${\bf x}_1 ,  \ldots , {\bf x}_{n-1}$
(the *rejection* of ${\bf x}_n$), and ${\bf u}_{n\, \bot }$ the corresponding unit vector.
Therefore
$$
Vol\left( {{\bf V}_n^{\left( m \right)} } \right) = \left\| {{\bf V}_n^{\left( m \right)} } \right\|
 = \left\| {{\bf V}_{n - 1}^{\left( m \right)} } \right\|\;\left\| {{\bf x}_n  \cdot {\bf u}_{n\; \bot } } \right\|
 = {\rm "base"}\, \times \,{\rm "height"}
$$

Comment: Grazie per il suggerimento, anche io sono originario di Rieti!

Comment: ehps.. what a coincidence ! :) (we shall talk in english on this site ..)

Comment: Thinking about a specific case of this problem when the plane is parallel to one of the face of the cube, then the projection of the cube on the plane is $l^2$ where $l$ is the side of the cube. I think that in this case the projection of the cube on the perpendicular of the plane is $l$ and seems to contradict the statement of the problem

Comment: Ah the above is not an issue since $l=1$

Comment: @Mattiatore:  In fact! but in any case you always have that the volume is preserved under rotation. Let's talk in this [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/141298/parallelotope?tab=general)

Comment: should better clear now